# how to use showmenu in listview Flutter

Tags: flutter

It's a chat and I want when I click in any item (message) in listview to popup something like this.
I tried to use showmenu but I stuck in position thing as I can only pass the position with key in the widget but it's every item in listview and key must be unique so I do not know how to handle this.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to do this in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908409/i-want-to-do-this-in-flutter)

Comment: That is, his previous question, may be didnot fulfil proper way, thats why people vote to close @christopher

Comment: @evan I'm aware. I'm one of the close voters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flutter package to do this. Use [popup_menu](https://pub.dev/packages/popup_menu).

Comment: It also needs  a key

Comment: What key? I just used it before, thats why i write it. You can use it too

Comment: Thanks, dude .. I have got mixed up but I solved it out